# How to change this code to work on Word rather that Excel

Tags: vba, ms-word

Currently I use code to turn specific words in an Excel file bold. I've been requested to do the same for a Word file, but I'm not sure how to get this code to work on Word instead. I really don't want to have to re-invent the wheel, when the base work is already done. Below is the code I use:

```
 Sub FindAndBoldTool()
    Dim xFind As String
    Dim xCell As Range
    Dim xTxtRg As Range
    Dim xCount As Long
    Dim xLen As Integer
    Dim xStart As Integer
    Dim xRg As Range
    Dim xTxt As String
    On Error Resume Next
    If ActiveWindow.RangeSelection.Count > 1 Then
      xTxt = ActiveWindow.RangeSelection.AddressLocal
    Else
      xTxt = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.AddressLocal
    End If
    Set xRg = Application.InputBox("Please select data range:", "FAB Tool", xTxt, , , , , 8)
    If xRg Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    On Error Resume Next
    Set xTxtRg = Application.Intersect(xRg.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, xlTextValues), xRg)
    If xTxtRg Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "There are no cells with text"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    xFind = Trim(Application.InputBox("What do you want to BOLD?", "FAB Tool", , , , , , 2))
    If xFind = "" Then
        MsgBox "No text was listed", vbInformation, "FAB Tool"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    xLen = Len(xFind)
    For Each xCell In xTxtRg
        xStart = InStr(xCell.Value, xFind)
        Do While xStart > 0
            xCell.Characters(xStart, xLen).Font.Bold = True
            xCount = xCount + 1
            xStart = InStr(xStart + xLen, xCell.Value, xFind)
        Loop
    Next
    If xCount > 0 Then
        MsgBox "number of " & CStr(xCount) & " text be bolded!", vbInformation, "FAB Tool"
    Else
        MsgBox "Not find the specific text!", vbInformation, "FAB Tool"
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: It will be more effort to convert your existing code than to write a word method from scratch.

Comment: *the base work is already done* - not quite. Actually, not at all. 99% of this code works against the Excel object model (`MsgBox`, `CStr`, and `InStr` calls don't). Sure at a [very] high abstraction level it's `MakeThingsBold`, and you can very well `MakeThingsBold` in Word too, but *how* you'll do it, and what objects and types need to get involved are a whole world apart. You *do* need to rewrite it from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this.

```
Sub looptest()

    Dim xTxtRg As Range
    Set xTxtRg = ActiveDocument.Range

    Dim xTxt As String
    xTxt = "FAB Tool"

        With xTxtRg.Find
            Do While .Execute(FindText:=xTxt, MatchWholeWord:=True, Forward:=True) = True
                With xTxtRg
                    xTxtRg.Bold = True
                End With
                xTxtRg.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
            Loop
        End With    
End Sub
```